# mongodb: count occurrences in two columns

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that has four columns: `object1, object2, selectedObject, unselectedObject`. `object1` and `object2` are two random objects from a collection (the collection contains the results of various matchups between two objects each time). I want to create a pipeline that shows for each distinct object in the `object1` column, how many times it appeared in the `selectedObject` column, and how many times it appeared in the `unselectedObject` column. Grouping and filtering according to just one column seems easy enough, but I want to display the results from both columns side by side, and various methods I tried for doing so failed.

For example, if the collection I have is:

```
{ID: 1, Object1: A, Object2: B, selected: A, Unselected: B}
{ID: 1, Object1: A, Object2: C, selected: C, Unselected: A}
{ID: 1, Object1: A, Object2: B, selected: B, Unselected: A}
{ID: 1, Object1: B, Object2: A, selected: B, Unselected: A}
{ID: 1, Object1: A, Object2: C, selected: C, Unselected: A}
{ID: 1, Object1: C, Object2: A, selected: C, Unselected: A}
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
{ Object: A, Selected: 1, Unselected: 5}
{ Object: B, Selected: 2, Unselected: 1}
{ Object: A, Selected: 3, Unselected: 0}
```

Comment: Would you show a small example collection and your desired output?  It's not completely clear to me how you want to aggregate.

Comment: sorry, added an example and a bit of context. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "distinctTypes": {
        "$addToSet": "$Object1"
      },
      docs: {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$distinctTypes"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      Object: "$distinctTypes",
      Selected: {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$docs",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$item.selected",
                "$distinctTypes"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      Unselected: {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$docs",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$item.Unselected",
                "$distinctTypes"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Explanation:

1. Group the documents into a list, and find distinct object types using the $group.
2. Unwind the distinct object type using $unwind.
3. Calculate Selected and unselected counts using $filter and $size.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cXhw30SE7gY)

Answer (score 1):

I like [@charchit-kapoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74050879/1409374).  And just to show another way (not as nice looking, nor probably as performant for small-ish collections) that might help if the entire collection is too large for a single `"$group"` stage, this also works.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "Objects": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$Object1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Selected": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$selected",
            "count": {"$count": {}}
          }
        }
      ],
      "Unselected": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$Unselected",
            "count": {"$count": {}}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Objects": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Objects",
          "as": "object",
          "in": {
            "Object": "$$object._id",
            "Selected": {
              "$cond": [
                {"$in": ["$$object._id", "$Selected._id"]},
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$Selected.count",
                    {"$indexOfArray": ["$Selected._id", "$$object._id"]}
                  ]
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            "Unselected": {
              "$cond": [
                {"$in": ["$$object._id", "$Unselected._id"]},
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$Unselected.count",
                    {"$indexOfArray": ["$Unselected._id", "$$object._id"]}
                  ]
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$Objects"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$Objects"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5r8cXDl1NnA).